# Number of integral values of $\alpha$ if equation $\sin^{–1}x + |x – \alpha| = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Number of integral values of $\alpha$ if equation $\arcsin(x) + |x – \alpha| = 0$ has at-least one solution, is:

My approach is as follow

$x\in[-1,1]$

$\arcsin(x)\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

$\arcsin(x) =- |x – a| $

I checked it desmos.com and the number of integral solution is $3$ but not able to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing down your path:
$$|x-\alpha|∈ [0,\pi/2]$$ (modulus result can't be negative)
$$-\pi/2≤x-\alpha≤\pi/2$$
$$x∈[\alpha-\pi/2, \alpha+\pi/2]$$
which you can compare to [-1,1] such that it has something in common, which yields $x = -2,-1,0,1,2 $
but for x = 1,2 it reaches the minimum value of $-\pi/2$ way after the other one does therefore no solution.

I would have done the smart thing and compared them via a rough graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\arcsin x+|x-\alpha|$. If $x\in(0,1]$ then $f(x)>0$. So, it is enough to look for solutions of $f(x)=0$ in the interval $[-1,0].$

$f(0)=|\alpha|\geq 0$ and in order to apply intermediate-value theorem we set $f(-1)=-\tfrac\pi 2+|\alpha+1|<0$ which has integer solutions $\alpha=-2,-1,0$. We claim that $f(x)=0$ has no solution for other integer values of $\alpha$.

For $\alpha\in\Bbb Z$, $\alpha\leq-3$, $f(x)\geq -\tfrac\pi 2+|\alpha|-1>0.$ So, $f(x)=0$ has no solution.

For $\alpha\geq2$, $$f(x)\geq \arcsin(-1)+|0-\alpha|=-\tfrac\pi 2+|\alpha|>0$$
so $f(x)=0$ has no solution.

For $\alpha=1$, for all $x\in[-1,1]$, we have $f(x)=\arcsin x+1-x$. Now, $f'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1\geq 0$ and thus $f(x)$ is increasing function. But, $f(-1)=2-\tfrac\pi 2>0.$ So, $f(x)=0$ has no solution.